# count all values and group by with count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
SELECT poll_numbers.number_title as totale_stemmen,  
       count(poll_stemmen.number_id) as stem 
FROM poll_stemmen
LEFT JOIN poll_numbers on number_id = poll_numbers.id
group by poll_stemmen.number_id
```

And the output is like this:

```
totale_stemmen stem    
name             1    
another          1
```

But how can i count the total number of stem together? in this result it would be 2.

here is the table layout:

```
poll_stemmen    
number_id, id

poll_numbers
id, number_title
```

sample data:

```
id, number_id
1   2
2   8
3   8
4   8

id, number_title
2   title_1
8   title_2

expected output:
number_title, count_number, total_number
title_1       1             4
title_2       3             4
```

Comment: @JeremyC. It can't, i want to count the total number of rows in the poll_stemmen table, and i want to count the total poll_numbers per id

Comment: can you give us some example data and expected result?

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your query to get count per `number_id` and use a sub-query to get overall count:

```
SELECT number_title, COUNT(*) AS count_number,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM poll_stemmen
        WHERE number_id IN (SELECT id FROM poll_numbers)) AS total_number
FROM poll_numbers AS pn
LEFT JOIN poll_stemmen AS ps ON ps.number_id = pn.id
GROUP BY ps.number_id
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62b2f6/1)

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, you would just use window functions.  But, MySQL doesn't support this.

One method is to use a subquery, either in the `from` clause or `select`:

```
SELECT n.number_title, count(s.number_id) as stem,
       x.total_number
FROM poll_stemmen s LEFT JOIN
     poll_numbers n
     on s.number_id = n.id CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT count(*) as total_number FROM poll_stemmen) x
group by s.number_id;
```

One advantage of putting the query in the `from` clause is that you know it will be executed only once.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT PN.`number_title`, count(PS.numberid)  
FROM `poll_stemmen` PS 
LEFT JOIN `poll_numbers` PN on PS.`numberid`=PN.`id` 
GROUP BY(PS.`numberid`)
```

It will be helpful if you provide table structure as this query will count total stems of same title

Comment: I have added the table structure

Comment: can you please add the sample data too

Comment: i have added sample data

Comment: i have checked this is running fine SELECT PN.`number_title`, count(PS.numberid)  FROM `poll_stemmen` PS inner join `poll_numbers` PN on PS.`numberid`=PN.`id` group by(PS.`numberid`)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT p.number_title as number_title,
        count(p.number_id) as count_number,
        (select count(p1.id) FROM `poll_numbers` p1) as total_number  
FROM `poll_numbers` p group by number_title
```